# How to loop and generate text in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a list

```
$scope.options = [
    { id:1, val: "Item 1"},
    { id:2, val: "Item 2"},
    { id:3, val: "Item 3"}
];
```

I want to be able to generate a list of xml elements

```
    <Name>{{option.id}}</Name>
    <Value>{{option.val}}SAS</Value>
```

I want to be able to generate it *inside* a text area

```
   <textarea>
    // some kind of loop here
    <Name>{{option.id}}</Name>
    <Value>{{option.val}}SAS</Value>
   </textarea>
```

The ng-repeat element seems to require to be in some of type of element such as option, div, etc.

This won't work for me. I need it to simply generate text strings *inside* a textarea.

Could someone please provide an example?

Comment: Might have to construct that manually and append it to the `textarea`

Comment: I need to be able to use ng-repeat *inside* a textarea. Anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, a custom function in your controller might help:

```
$scope.xmlGenerator = function() {
    var xml = "";
    angular.forEach($scope.options, function(key, value) {
        xml += "<Name>" +value.id+"</Name><Value>" + value.val + "SAS</Value>";
    }
}
```

And in your `textarea`

```
<textarea>{{xmlGenerator()}}</textarea>
```